# How do I draw a packed 16-bit pixel format texture with metal?

Tags: textures, metal, fragment-shader

I am new to metal and I managed to draw simple 32-bit rgba textures, but I cannot find any example on how to draw a 16-bit one (5_5_5_1 bgra, 5_6_5 bgr or 4_4_4_4 bgra).

I think the creation of the texture is ok:

```
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatB5G6R5Unorm;
bytesPerRow = 2*textureDescriptor.width;
```

I guess the problem is in the fragment function:

```
fragment float4 fragmentShaderTexture(VertexTexTriangleOut in [[stage_in]],
                                 texture2d<ushort> colorTexture [[ texture(0) ]])
{



constexpr sampler textureSampler;

const ushort4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.texCoords);

float4 colors = float4(colorSample);

return  colors;
}
```

Comment: What format is `colorTexture` in? If it's also a packed 16-bit texture, you may be reading unnormalized values. To get values in the range 0-1, which you seem to be expecting, you might need to use a parameter of type `texture2d<half>` or `texture2d<float>`.

Comment: Are you running your program on macOS?

Comment: `MTLPixelFormatB5G6R5Unorm` is marked as unavailable on macOS, so I don't think this program would compile.